# Error while importing projects

Tags: gradle, libgdx

While importing projects into eclipse i have this error:

*Cannot find System Java Compiler. Ensure that you have installed a JDK (not just a JRE) and configured your JAVA_HOME system variable to point to the according directory. Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-all.zip'.*

As I have checked i need to set JAVA_HOME (i have the JDK on my computer), but i dont have a clue how to do that.

Comment: Try adding the %JAVA_HOME%/bin directory into PATH system variable

Comment: task is done. i have edit path to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin, but error still persists

Comment: well i have managed to do something with this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Atu3ce2-dYg

just that i cant manage to get last part in cmd to work, but if i write just javac it recognizes it

Comment: The path is C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20 not C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin- Check my answer below

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I had lots of similar problems and I think that the best solution is to specify JDK location manually. In order to do it:

Add two files  to project root folder
`gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_03
```

and `local.properties`:

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_03
```

You should change `org.gradle.java.home value` to JDK path in your system. If you will have the same problem with android SDK add `sdk.dir=/Users/alonzilberman/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130917/sdk` to your `local.properties`.

After adding files refresh gradle build.

Comment: here is some easier way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913397/when-i-am-running-gradle-project-via-eclipse-i-got-some-exception

Comment: For me just updating the gradle.properties file worked. Also, this file is present by default in gradle project's root dir.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same message while trying to build a project in Android Studio.
After hours of research, trying different versions of JDK (from 8 to 6) I found this answer that fixed my problem:
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/mac-gradle-issues-with-finding-using-jdk-7-the-usual-answers-to-this-question-arent-working-expert-required/2553/24

The reason was that the AUSKey package installed a tools.jar in /Library/Java/Extensions directory that derailed Gradle looking for the compiler. Removing that file fixed the problem and I can now build in Android Studio.

Comment: nicely done. Also its sometimes funny how this programs work in some occasions

Answer (score 1):

Create a new system variable called `JAVA_HOME` and add

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25
```

It's because your environment variable isn't pointing to your jdk folder. Don't point it to your bin folder.