# Ensure that you have installed a JDK (not just a JRE) and configured your JAVA_HOME system variable to point to the according directory

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle, libgdx

I know this question is answered here [Error while importing projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613693/error-while-importing-projects) but I don't know where to find the AUSKey package that install's a tools.jar in /Library/Java/Extensions directory. I'm unable to ask the this question on the original answer because of reputation. I'm using eclipse and don't know if I should be looking in the project directory or the eclipse directory for the tools.jar. I'm assuming that this is the problem as I have a Java SDK installed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hopefully I'm not misunderstanding your question. I'm not familiar with AUSKey, but the little reading I just did seems to indicate that the extraneous items it adds to the Extensions directory, particularly tools.jar, can be removed manually, which seems to have fixed a number of other users' problems.

Comment: Yeah that's where I'm lost, I imagined I just delete them but where's the extensions directory I'm suppose to delete them from.  I found a couple of sources saying the same thing but don't know if its my project directory or is it something in eclipse I'm looking for, Sorry if I'm not 100% clear still only learning this stuff and haven't got my head around it yet.

Comment: Looks like it's going to be your standard /Library/Java/Extensions directory. Take a look at [Extension Libraries](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1170/_index.html).

Comment: Thanks that explains things better.