# In android studio i'm getting the below error while running

Tags: android

In android studio i'm getting this error while running the project.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.

> Cannot find System Java Compiler. Ensure that you have installed a JDK (not just a JRE) and configured your JAVA_HOME system variable to point to the according directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio installation on Windows 7 fails, no JDK found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found)

Comment: your ans [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38735609/7676637)

Comment: One of these questions where the question itself contains already the answer. Make it a habit to actually read and understand error messages. This helps a lot!

Comment: Answer = > `Ensure that you have installed a JDK (not just a JRE) ....`

Answer (score 2):

First you set JAVA_HOME variable in system environment variables.
Means MyComputer Properties => Advanced System settings => Environment variables => System Variables add new variable, variable name JAVA_HOME and value jdk installation path like C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79

Answer (score 0):

Its written there

> Ensure that you have installed a JDK (not just a JRE) and configured your JAVA_HOME system variable to point to the according directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Jdk in the system and mention the path in studio by clicking the following File->Project Structure->SDK location -> JDK location

Answer (score 0):

Go to File->Other Settings->Default Project Structure->SDKs. Then change or set the JDK home path.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the steps and  and check if jdk is configured if not do so....

[image]